# Javascript infinite loop to update entities

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing a game in javascript and on the server that does the world/map services I also need to add a command that updates all entities.

Let us say that an entity/monster is moving this means that a constant update is sent to all connected clients.

If I do something like

```
while(true)
  sendToAllConnectedClientsNearToThisMonster(data)
  items.forEach
     checkIfItemHasNotExpiredYet(item)
     deleteItemFromWorldIfExpired()
```

But at the same time, the same service is doing other stuff like handling the packets coming in and out. Encrypting Decrypting packets. Routing Packets, Forwarding chat packet to chat server...etc..

Will this not block my node.js server? What is the proper way of handling such tasks?

Comment: (a small tip: for handling expiration I use a timeout) You should take a look at bukkit to see how do they do that.

Comment: timeout can keep checking per few second without blocking all other functions?

Comment: @Vinz243 bukkit seems to be written in Java not Javascript.

Comment: timeout is a function that executes after a time. I use it when for example, I want to store IP addresses for a time (let's say a minute) and then remove it. Bukkitis written in java, yes, but you can take a look nnontheless. It is a minecraft server so there a lot of monster movements. If youprefer there is https://github.com/NetEase/lordofpomelo but I'm not sure of its "value"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setInterval`, it executes your function every X (in this example 250) milliseconds. This way you are not blocking your server. Since node.js is single threaded you should always follow the law of turns: Never wait. Never Block. And finish fast!

Here is your pseudo code wrapped in setInterval:

```
setInterval( function() {
  sendToAllConnectedClientsNearToThisMonster(data)
  items.forEach
     checkIfItemHasNotExpiredYet(item)
     deleteItemFromWorldIfExpired()
}, 250);
```

http://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setinterval_callback_delay_arg

Comment: single threaded which means it can only do 1 task at any given time right? Must be the reason to defer unimportant tasks from time to time?

Comment: Yes, you can only do one thing at a time

Comment: Seems like I should break down my services to smaller parts and just have 1 service to route all incoming TCP packets. hmmm. thanks anyways.